# Can I DISABLE the lock screen bypass for incoming calls?

Tags: lock-screens, calls

I use a pattern lock on my phone to prevent bumdialing. Recently I got a call when the phone was in my pocket, which I was only aware of when I later on took out my phone to look at it. I had accidentally rejected the call while it was in my pocket, before even the first ring.

When receiving a call, I get no lock screen first - it bypasses straight to the phone app. I don't want this. I want to have to enter the pattern and THEN answer the phone. That way, I'm not going to accidentally answer or reject calls with the phone in my pocket.

I can find lots and lots of questions on how to bypass the lock screen on incoming call, but nothing trying to disable bypassing that's already there. Any ideas?

I'm using Cyanogenmod 12.1-20151117 (Android 5.1.1).

Comment: It is [a Window Manager flag](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/InCallUI/+/master/src/com/android/incallui/InCallActivity.java#143) responsible for this. Perhaps some xposed magic could help here.

Comment: If that's the standard phone code then what I want is impossible, and the behaviour is hardcoded. I'll need to look for an alternative phone call app.